# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 107654: invalid start byte Django database change to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I recently attempted to switch databases on my Django project from the default SQLite to MySQL.
After setting up MySQL accordingly, I used the following command:

```
python manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json
# to export existing data into a json file
```

After I set up the MySQL db in settings.py and doing all the migrations, trying to load the json file to the db with the command:

```
python manage.py loaddata datadump.json
# should return sth like "Installed 59 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)"
```

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 107654: invalid start byte
```

Now I tried setting the default charset of the mysql DB to utf8 but nothing happened.
When I click on the `datadump.json` file in Pycharm, I also get the following warning, I do not know whether it is relevant or not:

```
File was loaded with the wrong encoding: UTF-8
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:
I used Pycharm's interface to reload the datadump.json file with an UTF-8 encoding(you should be prompted to change it at the top when you open the file).
I also had an unclosed parenthesis at one point in the file and everything worked after fixing those two things.